# Responsive JavaScript: "Refresh" page depending on screen width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, width, screen-orientation

i've made a responsive website with a horizontal menu. I wanted to make the menu a toggle drop down when a lower screen resolution is reached. The JQuery-Toggle works fine and i tried this to "make it responsive":

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 768) {

    $(document).ready(function(e){

       $('#menubutton').on('click',function(){

          $('#main-nav').slideToggle();

       });

    })
}
```

This works also fine but not by changing the windowsize directly in the browser – i have to resfresh the page manually to load the Script!

Is there a way to "refresh" the page when the needed screen width is reached (768 px)? …and vise versa!

thanx,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe instead of refreshing the page on every resize, you can do:

```
var mainNavActivated = false;
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $('#menubutton').on('click',function(){
        if(mainNavActivated || document.documentElement.clientWidth < 768){
            window.mainNavActivated=true;
            $('#main-nav').slideToggle();
        }
   });
})
```

which is binding click anyway and making it work when the window is "narrow"

Comment: hey thanks.. this is almost nearly what i wanted.. is it possible to make the script "onloaded" by resizing the window to maximum? right now the menu disappears…

Comment: so when you maximize the window from a narrow state, the opened menu disappears? does it disappear by simply resizing above 768 width or only when maximized?

Comment: no, the menu disappears, when i resize the website to a higher state than 768px after loading the script. Lower that 768px the script gets loaded and i can use the toggle. but it is not working vice versa: the script is still in "toggle mode" afer resizing it! i hope this makes it clear, english is not my native language ;-)

Comment: so, you want once the slide menu is activated, you want to keep it that way even the window resizes back right? I updated my answer

Comment: thanks but no, sorry.. i want it to be deactivated. but the more i think about it, maybe that specific thing (disappearing menu after resizing window) is not an problem of the javascript-code... hmm, i don't know.. anyway: thanks alot!

Comment: maybe if you share more code (without getting fired :), I can come up with something more helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).resize()`. It will call your function every time the window is resized by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resize` event.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // here your code
});
```

Comment: …i tried that but the problem is now: the toggle opens and closes til infinity?!?! and when i resize the window to maximum the menu disappears (the script is still loaded)!?!

Comment: You sould check every time if the size is small or big. If it's small you should execute your code, otherwise you should execute the rollback. You must consider both cases.